# JBoss stop tail on server restart

Tags: linux, shell, jboss, jboss6.x

I have a shell script that resarts JBoss following a new deployment as a scheduled task. The problem is that jboss automatically tails the server.log on restart which means my shell script will not stop until the server is stopped again, since a ctrl-c doesnt seem to kill the tail, Im not sure how to get around this?

I have seen some other examples where people use kill -9 to stop the tail?

Ideally I would like the output from server.log up until the point where the server is up and running, but this could also be on a timer (stop tail after 60sec?)

This is the script so far...

```
    echo "1) Archive Found To Deploy"
    cd /home/webApp/toDeploy
    chown jboss Archive.ear
    chgrp jboss Archive.ear
    mv Archive.ear /opt/jboss/server/default/deploy/
    echo "2) Archive Copied to Deploy Folder"
    /etc/init.d/jboss restart
    echo "3) Server Restarted"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use &

```
echo "1) Archive Found To Deploy"
cd /home/webApp/toDeploy
chown jboss Archive.ear
chgrp jboss Archive.ear
mv Archive.ear /opt/jboss/server/default/deploy/
echo "2) Archive Copied to Deploy Folder"
/etc/init.d/jboss restart &
echo "3) Server Restarted"
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt stop the cron output being filled up from the server log (the output is only emailed when the server is stopped again)

Comment: I remember we had the same problem back then it was resolved by modifying something. Have you tried this? /etc/init.d/jboss restart > /dev/null